# Input coordinates into two separate arrays from file trouble

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I have a file with x and y coordinates and am trying to input the x coordinates into a single 1D array and the y coordinates into another 1D array.

The data file is in the following format

```
(x coordinate)(y coordinate)
(x coordinate)(y coordinate)
(x coordinate)(y coordinate) (x coordinate)(y coordinate) 
(x coordinate)(y coordinate) (x coordinate)(y coordinate)
```

The file looks like this. This is only a small portion of the file as we are never given anything with more then 5,000 points.

```
5.675207 -0.571210
0.728926 0.666069
2.290909 0.751731 2.004545 0.907396
0.702893 0.646427 5.909504 -0.365045
2.082645 0.871841 5.597107 -0.633507
6.117769 -0.164663 6.091736 -0.190282
5.571074 -0.653433 4.503719 -0.978307
3.983058 -0.745620
3.670661 -0.504729
5.857438 -0.413001
```

So far I have the following code already finished:

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

int count = 0;
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;  
double points[5000]; 
double x_coordinate[5000] = { 0 };
double y_coordinate[5000] = { 0 };

if (argc < 3)
{
    cout << "Incorrect usage:  prog.exe filenname number" << endl;
    cout << "Exiting now, please try again." << endl;
    return -1;
}

fin.open(argv[1]);
if (!fin)
{
    cout << "Error opening file \"" << argv[1] << "\", exiting." << endl;
    return -1;
}

fout.open(argv[2]); 

while (fin >> points[count]) 
{ 
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        fin >> x_coordinate[count]; 
    }
    else
    {
        fin >> y_coordinate[count]; 
    }
    count++; 
}

fin.close();
fout.close(); 

return 0;

}
```

I outputted the contents of my array just to make sure that they were inputted properly and for the x_coordinate array, I received the following output:

```
 -0.57121 0 0.751731 0 0.646427 0 0.871841 0 -0.164663 0 -0.653433 0 -0.74562 0 -0.413001 0 0.990358 0 -0.892387 0 -0.77929 0 0.835618 0 -0.999672 0 0.129798 0 -0.340688 0 -0.728578 0 -0.388408 0 0.420644 0 0.999065 0 0.556654 0 -0.435838 0 -0.779798 0 -0.710501 0 0.995461 0 -0.138933 0 0.875928 0 -0.972772 0 -0.527719 0 0.956751 0 0.372859 0 -0.987763 0 0.845169 0 -0.613152 0 0.703984
```

And for the y_coordinate array I get the following output:

```
0 0.666069 0 0.907396 0 -0.365045 0 -0.633507 0 -0.190282 0 -0.978307 0 -0.504729 0 0.858796 0 -0.994541 0 -0.459839 0 0.849633 0 -0.996983 0 -0.99692 0 0.599134 0 0.93742 0 -0.983368 0 -0.63288 0 0.976531 0 0.34858 0 0.103944 0 -0.240329 0 0.961729 0 -0.914335 0 0.768643 0 -0.112302 0 -0.672316 0 0.954271 0 -0.89202 0 0.181224 0 0.785033 0 0.356447 0 0.467288 0 0.474704 0 -0.728022
```

Is there something wrong in my fin statements? What can I do to fix it and get rid of every other 0 in the arrays. I'm a beginner programmer and it's taking me a long time to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If your file is made up of x and y coordinates, why are you reading into `points[count]`?

Comment: We are going to need all the points in an array for a later part of the program. My only concern right now is sorting the x and y coordinates into their own separate arrays.

Comment: But if you read something into `points`, then you can't also read it into either `x_coordinate` or `y_coordinate`.  You could *copy* it from `points` into either of those, but you can't re-read it.

Comment: There's something wrong with the logic, you should *either* have two arrays (one for X and one for Y) *or* one array of points, each point being a `std::pair<double>` or any similar structure.

Comment: I see your point! Any suggestions on how to just get the two arrays for X and Y?

Comment: something like `fin >> X[count] >> Y[count]; count++;`  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all of the value to go into `points` *and* have those values broken up between `x_coordinate` and `y_coordinate`, then something like this would do for your loop body:

```
if (count % 2 == 0)
{
    x_coordinate[count / 2] = points[count];
}
else
{
    y_coordinate[count / 2] = points[count];
}
count++;
```

If you only need them to go into the `coordinate` arrays, replace `points[count]` with a simple `double` variable wherever it is used.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix:

```
if (count % 2 == 0)
{
    fin >> x_coordinate[count / 2]; 
}
else
{
    fin >> y_coordinate[count / 2]; 
}
count++;
```

E.g. when you are reading the third value, `count=2`, so `count % 2 == 0` and `count / 2 == 1`, it's `x_coordinate[1]`.

Update. Noticed the strange thing with `fin >> points[count]`. I would do the following:

```
while (fin >> x_coordinate[count]) {
  fin >> y_coordinate[count];
  count++;
}
```

The full code (to be clear):

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;  
double x_coordinate[5000] = {}; // is enough to zeroify, but is it necessary?
double y_coordinate[5000] = {};

if (argc < 3)
{
    cout << "Incorrect usage:  prog.exe filenname number" << endl;
    cout << "Exiting now, please try again." << endl;
    return 1; // usually only small non-negative numbers like 0-127 are valid
}

fin.open(argv[1]);
if (!fin)
{
    cout << "Error opening file \"" << argv[1] << "\", exiting." << endl;
    return 1;
}

fout.open(argv[2]); 
if (!fout) // also needed
{
    cout << "Error opening file \"" << argv[2] << "\", exiting." << endl;
    return 1;
}  

int count = 0; // declaration closer to the place where the variable is used
while (fin >> x_coordinate[count]) {
    fin >> y_coordinate[count];
    count++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    fout << x_coordinate[i] << ' ' << y_coordinate[i] << endl;
}

fin.close();
fout.close(); 

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I tried doing that and outputted the x_coordinate array just to be sure, but I ended up with the following output: -0.57121 
    0.751731 
    0.646427 
    0.871841 
    -0.164663 
    -0.653433

Comment: Updated the answer.